# graph model library in javascrript

Tags: javascript, graph

I am looking for a graph library in javascript which offers graph algorithm for directed and undirected graphs (like calculating Minimum Spanning Trees, Shortest Path etc). I wont need any layout algorithm as I want to implement this with d3.js . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in Cytoscape.js, which can be used both for visualisation or headlessly for analysis:

http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/

You may find it easier to use just Cytoscape.js rather than building a whole new visualisation with d3, but you could use Cytoscape.js headlessly with a d3 visualisation on top if you want.

Disclaimer: I developed Cytoscape.js

Comment: Does Cytoscape provide a method which returns the ancestor tree of a node (and what is its name)?  Note, I am not referring to compound nodes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/chen0040/js-graph-algorithms

it provides javascript implementatino of the following graph algorithms for directed and undirected graphs:

- Depth First Search
- Breadth First Search
- Connected Components for undirected graph
- Topoloical Sort
- Strongly Connected Components for directed graph
- Minimum Spanning Tree for weighted graph (Kruskal, Prim Lazy, Prim Eager)
- Shortest Paths (Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, Topological Sort on DAG)
- MaxFlow-MinCut (Ford-Fulkerson)